# Running multiple instances of a python file with two input files using GNU Parallel on an HPC system with SLURM

Tags: python, hpc, slurm, gnu-parallel

I try to run a single python file 240 times in parallel (since each
individual file run takes about 9 min) on an HPC-system. Ideally each python file should run on a single core. There are 24 cores per node. The python file takes two input files, one from each set:

- `CN_ONLY0.pdb` up to `CN_ONLY239.pdb`
- `I_ONLY0.pdb` up to `I_ONLY239.pdb`.

When I run the below posted code:

```
parallel="parallel --delay .2         \
                    -j $SLURM_NTASKS   \
                   --joblog runtask.log \
                   --resume              \
                   --max-args=2"

srun="srun --exclusive -N1 -n1 --cpus-per-task=1 --cpu-bind=cores"

find . -type f \( -name "CN_ONLY*.pdb" -o -name "I_ONLY*.pdb" \) |
        sort -t Y -k 2 -g     |
        TMPDIR=$SLURM_SCRATCH \
        $parallel python python_test.py
```

It runs the Python program correctly, but does not distribute the program to all the different requested CPUs.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: **Step 0. :** consult the best-practices with your HPC-infrastructure **Technical Support**, there is the best place to start from. Always.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use GNU parallel when SLURM itself proivdes that functionality via **array jobs** (or job arrays). Simply add `--array=1-240` to the `srun` command and then submit the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

id=$(expr ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID} - 1)
python python_test.py CN_ONLY${id}.pdb I_ONLY${id}.pdb
```

What happens is that SLURM will launch this script 240 times and set the value of `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` to a different value in each of them, ranging from 1 to 240. It is then trivial to subtract one from this value and use it to generate the names of the script arguments.